# Input string was not in a correct format. Expected type in Decimal type

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, oracle, datatable

I am not inserting any value in `VOUCHER_NO` column and updating it.

But it is giving me error as

> Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <> in VOUCHER_NO Column. Expected type is Decimal.

Below is my code

```
drpayinfo[0]["VOUCHER_NO"] = e.Record["VOUCHER_NO"];
```

**Update**

I am using Oracle DB and its datatype is `NUMBER (10)`

Comment: Are you sure the error is from the line of code shown here?

Comment: @Filburt: yes I am sure

Comment: Pretty straightforward: either the value isn't convertable to the required type, or the error is caused by a different line of code than what you've displayed here.  Check the values in the debugger, then go line by line through the code to find the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems your `e.Record["VOUCHER_NO"]` have some unwanted content which is not convertible to decimal. Try this way checking before assignment or conversion

```
if(e.Record["VOUCHER_NO"] != "")
{
  drpayinfo[0]["VOUCHER_NO"] = Convert.ToDecimal(e.Record["VOUCHER_NO"]);
}
```

But more safer way to detect and ignore bad content is

```
decimal result;

if (Decimal.TryParse(e.Record["VOUCHER_NO"], out result))
{
    drpayinfo[0]["VOUCHER_NO"] = result;
}
else
{
    // do stuff if failed to parese
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126033/discussion-between-mostafiz-and-nad).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments on other answers, your value is an empty string. This cannot directly be converted to a decimal. You must decide some action to take instead.

They following code will try to convert it, and take an action if not. `TryParse` is your friend for conversions!

```
decimal num = 0;

if (!Decimal.TryParse(e.Record["VOUCHER_NO"], out num))
{
    //Throw some error, maybe set num to some default and assign...
    //The appropriate action in this situation depends on your needs.
}
else
{
    //You can safely assign the value
    drpayinfo[0]["VOUCHER_NO"] = num;
}
```